# Getting Apple TV 2 to work with third-party iPad app

Tags: ipad, appletv, airplay

I've got a non-Apple app which is supposed to use AirPlay to stream both video and audio to an Apple TV (or other AirPlay-enabled device). Following the AirPlay setup instructions on Apple's website, I turned on my Apple TV, and then, having started playback on my iPad, switched the output from the iPad to the Apple TV. The Apple TV plays audio, and responds to all of the iPad's playback controls, but there's no video. In fact, when the media shows up (as "now playing", under computers), it's shown to be an audio track: the Apple TV shows the default iTunes graphic for albums with no artwork.

I'm using the original iPad running iOS 5.1.1 (the latest this model supports)

Am I missing something here? Is it possibly that it's just an ill-coded app?

Comment: Does your iPad support AirPlay mirroring when you are browsing the main interface with the dock and the icons?

Comment: I don't think so; it's an original iPad running iOS 5. I haven't tried that, however.

Comment: OK - you don't get AirPlay mirroring on that hardware. I'll be able to offer an answer when I get back to my Apple TV and original iPad to test things. I'm sure many things like the Videos app do stream video to Apple TV, so you might figure out if it's the setup or the app by trying other apps in the mean time...

Comment: Have you tried any other ways to stream media on Apple TV? For example downloading wireless apps to work like a remote control: ArkMC, StreamtoMe, Bubble UPnP etc.?

Comment: @AlisaZlotenko I can't say I have, mostly because I haven't owned the AppleTV in question since late 2014... In any case, this would've been many firmware updates ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple's Apple TV 2 [AirPlay page](http://www.apple.com/appletv/airplay/) (in the footnotes at the bottom of that page):

> 1. AirPlay is available on all devices running iOS 4.3 or later. Some features require the latest software. Second-generation Apple TV or later required.
> 2. AirPlay Mirroring is available with iPad 2 or later; iPhone 4S; iMac (Mid 2011 or newer), Mac mini (Mid 2011 or newer), MacBook Air (Mid 2011 or newer), and MacBook Pro (Early 2011 or newer) with Mountain Lion.

This explains your situation as far as what you're describing, which sounds like mirroring. In my experience with the 1st gen iPad, there is usually a speaker icon next to the name of your Apple TV when you are attempting AirPlay and audio-only capability is available. When you're using hardware with video AirPlay capability (i.e., Mirroring), there is a TV icon next to the name of the Apple TV. Beyond the footnotes listed above, this is a sure indicator of your iPad to Apple TV connectivity options.